# rpi_firmware_get_throttled: X callbacks suppressed

Tags: voltage, firmware, logfiles

I have the following entry in my logs:

```
Oct 08 17:51:02 rpi-dash kernel: rpi_firmware_get_throttled: 9 callbacks suppressed
```

It is suspiciously surrounded by warnings about power:

```
Oct 08 17:48:07 rpi-dash kernel: Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
Oct 08 17:48:30 rpi-dash kernel: Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
Oct 08 17:51:02 rpi-dash kernel: rpi_firmware_get_throttled: 9 callbacks suppressed
Oct 08 17:51:02 rpi-dash kernel: Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
Oct 08 17:51:14 rpi-dash kernel: Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
```

This is repeated all across the logs.

My question: what does `rpi_firmware_get_throttled: 9 callbacks suppressed` mean, and what can be the consequence of a suppressed callback? Specifically - can it impact Wi-Fi stability?

I know why I have the under-voltage warnings and I am fine with this (this RPi is running like that for years and I can rebuild it in no time if this caused filesystem issues, which thankfully never happened).

I would like to understand what the consequences of the callback can be.